# אמר Divine Speech?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, speech-talking, nevua-prophecy, dream

ב"ה
I have heard this idea, but I could never find a source for it. The idea is that in certain circumstances when the Torah uses the word ואמר referring to Hashem speaking that it means that the communication was specifically through the medium of dreams and not spoken word. Does anyone know the source for this?

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35820/4794

Answer (score 1):

(I can't think of an explicit connection off the top of my head, but here goes):

The *Sifrei* (*B'midbar* 153) writes that Moshe Rabbeinu's prophecy was superior to that of other prophets, because Moshe sometimes prophesied on a level connoted by the word "*davar*", while other prophets prophesied on a lower level as connoted by the word "*amar*":

> זה הדבר, מגיד שכשם שנתנבא משה בכה אמר כך נתנבאו הנביאים בכה אמר ומוסיף עליהם משה שנאמר בו זה הדבר.

The Rambam (*Moreh N'vuchim* 2:45) maintains that other prophets experience prophecy via dreams, whereas Moshe's prophecy involved direct communication with HaShem:

> אבל אם אפשר שיראה הנביא עוד במראה הנבואה כאלו השם ידבר עמו, הוא רחוק אצלי, ולא יגיע פעל הכח המדמה לזה, ולא מצאנו זה הענין בשאר הנביאים, ולזה בארה התורה ואמרה במראה אליו אתודע בחלום אדבר בו, שם הדבור בחלום לבד ושם למראה הדבקות השכל והשפעתו, והוא אמרו במראה אליו אתודע, שהוא התפעל מן ידע ולא באר שבמראה ישמע דבר מהשם, וכאשר מצאתי הכתובים יעידו בדבר שמעו הנביא ויבאר שהוא במראה, אמרתי על צד המחשבה שאפשר שיהיה זה הדבר אשר ישמע בחלום, ולא יתכן כמותו במראה, הוא שיהיה השם ידמה לו שהוא ידבר עמו, זה כלו ע"צ המשך אחר הנראה, ואיפשר שיאמר האומר שכל מראה שתמצא בשמע דבור יהיה תחלת הענין ההוא מראה, ואחר כן הגיע להשתקע ושב חלום, כמו שבארנו באמרו ותרדמה נפלה על אברם, ואמרו זו תרדמה של נבואה, ויהיה כל דבור שישמע על אי זה צד שישמע, בחלום כמו שבא הכתוב בחלום אדבר בו

Perhaps the Rambam would specifically identify Moshe's "*davar*" prophecies as the direct ones.